# C# Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpcontext

I am trying to connect with a token bearer Authentication into a remote `WebApi` from my `.net Consoleapp`.

Despite the fact that my program returns with a success a token, in my `PostAsync` Method i get the following message:

> "Authorization has been denied for this request"

My code is the following

```
hHttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
HttpContent Content = new StringContent(string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ApiLoginUsername),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ApiLoginPassword)), Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/api/login", Content).Result;
string resultJSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginTokenResult>(resultJSON);
```

So far so good the code returns a Token and stores it in the result

The following part does the following with: With the token that i received i am trying to retrive some data

```
HttpContent TestContent = new StringContent(string.Format("Authorization","Bearer"+ result.AccessToken,"application/json"));
var Product = client.PostAsync("/api/Report",TestContent).Result;----> This is where it says Authorization denied
var test = Product.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return result;
```

Why am i getting in the `test` the message "Authorization has been denied for this request"
Am i missing something important in my code? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It could be a number of reasons, but my guess is that it's because there's no space between `"Bearer"` and `result.AccessToken`.

Comment: @Kirk thanks for the quick reply but it was not what you suggest

Comment: Authorization / Bearer is a request header.

Comment: @MikeCheel Ok...which means ?

Comment: @Kirk so your saying that maybe my program could be right? May am i missing the right way of setting my Parameters ?

Comment: Add that line to the request header. Try TestContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", <token value>)); You *might* need to just use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.118).aspx instead to send your request. And add the Authorization header directly to your request.

Comment: @MikeCheel does not seems to working

Comment: Did you try using HttpClient.SendAsync? Build your HttpRequestMessage and then add the header like I said above. Then call httpClient.SendAsync(). It's what I do.

Comment: @MikeCheel maybe you are correct because now i get "internal server error" as a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request could look something like this:

```
string uri = "/api/Report";
string token = "<token here>";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<base address>");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", token);

HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

In your code you are trying to post the Authorization blurb as string content where it should be in the request header.

Comment: Propably you are correct because now i get as response "Internal Server Error"